# Difference between filter and a where clause

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm always with my Access app..

As far as I know, when I execute a sql clause to my back end (accdb file), say

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id=1;
```

It gets filtered on the back end, then just one record is transmitted over the network.

My question is, when I open a form bounded with a query (no where clause) using a filter parameter, like

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form",,, strFilter
```

how many records are transmitted on the network? They get filtered like that sql clause or they get filtered locally, meaning a big pile of data has to be sent over the network?

I'm concerned about this because I have many subforms bounded to queries, then I open them in the main forms with filter parameter. And of course, the network here is not very good.

EDIT: The environment of my app is on a factory with no local server. All network/information thing is in company's headquarter 300km away, maybe a WAN.
Except upgrading to SQL server alike, do I have other solutions to make it more reliable? I've heard of something '**Citrix**', I happened to have a 'Citrix Neighborhood Agent Program' in my sys tray, can it host my app to make it faster?

Comment: With a remote desktop session on the server, data access speed would be higher and the risk of corruption lower.  You would need Access available on the server.  You will need to work out the details for Citrix.  I've done similar with plain old Windows remote desktop connection, and it works fine.  There is also Windows Terminal Service which can support remote desktop connections, if that's available on your server.

Comment: WTS is available on every Windows Server starting with Windows 2000. However, by default, there are only 2 available licenses, and they can be used only by users with admin rights on the server. But it's very easy to add CALs for non-admin users to be able to run RDP sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Jet/ACE requests data from a file server, the first thing it needs is the database header information, which has data structures describing the structure of the data file. This is information is requested once in your Access session, so it's really only an issue at startup.

When you then request a record, Jet/ACE uses the metadata it has about the file to request the relevant index pages for the table(s) involved, then uses those indexes to determine the minimum number of data pages to request.

With properly structured indexing and filters on primary keys the amount of data retrieved is actually quite minimal.

However, it's still going to be more than will allow proper response times across a WAN. Access was designed for use across a wired LAN, back in the days when the networking standard was 10BaseT (10Mbps). Anything less than that and you'll have problems. WiFi is right out, as well, but not because of bandwidth, but because of the unreliability of the connections.

When you need to support users remotely, the easiest solution is to host the Access application on a Windows Terminal Server. WTS is built on technology licensed from Citrix, so you'll often see the whole concept described as Citrix, but your default WTS setup is quite different from a Citrix installation. You have to pay extra for Citrix, and it gives you a lot of different features.

I've used WTS without Citrix in many environments and frankly can't see what the justification would be for Citrix (except when you have to support large numbers of remote users, i.e., in the range of 100 or more). WTS is installed on every Windows Server starting with Windows 2000 and is very easy to set up and configure.

The second easiest solution, in my opinion, is to upsize the back end to a server database and then rewrite for efficiency to insure you're using the server as much as possible and not pulling too much data across the wire.

A third solution would be Sharepoint, but I'm not experienced with that. It is definitely the direction that MS is pushing for Access apps in distributed setups, but it's quite complex and has a whole lot of features. I wouldn't recommend plunging into it without lots of preparation and significant corporate support.

Comment: Ok this answer give me a little confidence. So I know the data is limited to those that I want on the network... I have it discussed with my boss, and the Citrix thing here is not available for me. For sql server, maybe. So if I upgrade my app to base on a SQL SERVER, do I need to change all those code for the connection? (I'm using DAO, just link those tables like if they were local)

Comment: Citrix may not be available, but what about plain vanilla Windows Terminal Server? Every Windows Server since Windows 2000 has WTS installed by default, and all you need to use it is purchase and install the CALs for it -- it's that easy to set up. You may need to add some RAM, but only if you've got to support a lot of simultaneous users (10 are easily supported in 2GBs of RAM, for instance).

Comment: Upsizing a back end to SQL Server does not require any changes to your application. You use ODBC linked tables and program as before. There as some changes in your DAO recordsets (like adding the dbSeeChanges option), but not much. Once you've upsized, you'll then be able to tell what processes are slower than they were before and those can be moved server-side. However, note that I would recommend going the Terminal Server route before upsizing the back end, because it's MUCH less work.

Answer (score 2):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form",,, strFilter
```

*how many records are transmitted on the network?*

As many as match your strFilter condition.  So, if `WHERE id=1` returns one row in the earlier SELECT query, and strFiler = "id=1", that OpenForm will open the form with that single row as its record source.

The WhereCondition parameter is also available for DoCmd.OpenReport, and operates the same way as with OpenForm, which you also may find useful.

**Edit**: You should have an index to support the WHERE criteria whether you build it into the query or do it "ad hoc" with OpenForm WhereCondition.  With an index the database engine will read the index to find which rows match, then retrieve those rows.  So retrieval will be more efficient, and therefore faster, than forcing the engine to read every row to determine which of them include matches.

Comment: @Hansup, correct me if I'm wrong, but in your example, doesn't Access pull every record in the table across the network then filter the data locally? I thought having the criteria in the query would cause Access to pull only the 1 record across the network instead of the entire table.

Comment: @Tim With the OpenForm WhereCondition, Access VBA asks the database engine for only those rows which match.  The effect is like re-writing the form's Record Source "on-the-fly".  So with the WhereCondition it doesn't first pull all, then filter locally.

Comment: @HandsUp Today I've tried, with little things in the back end, it runs well, 2 or 3 seconds for a search or write. Will it be slower with the size of the backend growing?

Comment: Yes it will take longer as the table grows.  However, if your WhereCondition operates on an indexed field, it could take a lot of growth before a user would notice any slowdown.  Indexes are critical!

Comment: Also 2-3 seconds may be an improvement, but still seems too slow for me.  Try that Citrix approach you mentioned ... with Access running remotely on the server where the database is stored ... you should see faster performance (AND less risk of corrupting the database).

Comment: What Jet/ACE does is request the indexes needed to figure out the smallest number of data pages required to retrieve the data. If you haven't properly indexed your table, then you'll pull lots more data. If you're filtering on the PK, you'll pull the smallest amount of data possible. I would still never do it across a WAN, though -- that's just asking for trouble. You'd be better off upsizing the back end to a server database so you're really only sending the request and pulling back only the results.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with Access, there is not really a true back-end as there is with a bona-fide client-server engine like SQL Server or Oracle or Postgres.  Access uses a shared-file architecture where the client program itself "owns" chunks of the file on disk, as distinct from a message-passing architecture where the client program sends requests for data to a back-end engine process running on a server where that process "owns" the data.  **With shared-file, all work occurs on the client, so it is possible for freight-train-loads of data to be brought across the wire if the database file resides on a different machine**.

When you ask Access for data, it often reads a lot more data from the MDB file on disk and caches at the local client a lot more data than what your statement has asked for. Access tries to do this intelligently, anticipating your needs. "Now that I'm here", Access says, "I might as well make the expensive trip to disk worthwhile and grab a sh*tload of data". Don't get me wrong. I'm not an Access basher and have been using it for more than 10 years, from back in the days when LAN bandwidth was 10mbit/sec. Access is very good for some things. But Access can gobble up bandwidth like you wouldn't believe.

Read up on "keysets" in Access.

P.S. I am not the same Tim as the Tim who left you a comment.

Some useful links:

```
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824(v=office.12).aspx
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209126
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112112
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/128808
```

Comment: I got 2 different answer here ... But if it's like what you said, even if the 'SELECT ... WHERE' clause causes lots of data transmission.. So it will be slower and slower with the table gets bigger? Sounds not good to me..

Comment: @Tim...other Tim I mean...Rats! You were first, so I guess I should change mine. :)

Comment: I think you're vastly overstating the amount of data Jet/ACE retrieves. However, the problem is that when you go from a LAN environment (where the data amounts are not that big a deal) to a WAN, you've crossed the threshold where even the small amounts of data Access requests are going to be slow. Indeed, with a WAN, it will be slower with a server database on the other end, too -- this is the nature of most WANs in comparison to LANs in regard to available bandwidth.